# Is a bank job which is related to an ATM cards department haram?

Tags: halal-haram, work, banking

I was wondering if doing a job in bank which is related to ATM cards department is haram. This department is not involved in any interest transaction.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, banks in general runs on interest. Its entire profit is based on interest. So you can conclude that the employees salary (working in any department) is derived from the share of the interest that accounts for bank's profit.